# Error in train$label : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I am getting an: `Error in train$label:object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

```
library(caret)
inTrain  <- createDataPartition(train$label, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
training <- train.data[inTrain,]
testing  <- train.data[-inTrain,]
```

any help?

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing what `train` looks like.

Comment: Is that a typo? Should your code say `train.data$label` ?

Comment: neilfws: train <- read.csv("train.csv")